# Rename or add macro to module in a copied sheet from main workbook with vba

Tags: vba, copy

I have been working on a file i will use with lots of different functions and im using user form as "control panel" - i have been trying to get one function working here but i really dont find the solution.  Maybe someone here can help?   I have to say im far from experienced with vba but i find it really interesting to try and learn.

My question:  I have a code where i add shapes to a list, with also click and zoom function - i have also code that i copy this sheet into a new workbook and save it as .xlsm and i have the macro in the actual sheet i copied- So far so good.
But i dont manage to get the macro to work in the new workbook as it seems like since i have the macro in the sheet the new workbook call the macro  "sheet9.Zoom"  instead of actually just call it Zoom -   Is it possible to somehow rename the macro in the copied version in the vba code or make sure that the new workbook dont call it "sheet9.Zoom" so the function find the macro when clicking on the picture to zoom?   Everything here is beeing done using a Form as i want to make it as userfriendly as possible for my collegues :)

Here is the code i use for adding the Zoom function to the shapes :

```
Private Sub Commandbutton8_Click()
Set myDocument = Worksheets("Import")
myDocument.Shapes.SelectAll

Set sr = Selection.ShapeRange

Selection.OnAction = "Zoom_Click"
Range("e1").Select


End Sub

Sub Zoom_Click()

Dim shp As shape
    Dim big As Single, small As Single
    Dim shpDouH As Double, shpDouOriH As Double
    big = 0.8
    small = 0.11
    On Error Resume Next
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
    With shp
        shpDouH = .Height
        .ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        shpDouOriH = .Height
     
        If Round(shpDouH / shpDouOriH, 2) = big Then
            .ScaleHeight small, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ScaleWidth small, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ZOrder msoSendToBack
        Else
            .ScaleHeight big, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ScaleWidth big, msoTrue, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            .ZOrder msoBringToFront
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

And this is for the copy the sheet to new workbook.

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()


Dim MyPath As String

Dim MyFileName As String

Dim DateString As String

DateString = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd_hh_mm_ss_AM/PM")

MyFileName = DateString & "_" & "Pricelist"

If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".xlsm" Then MyFileName = MyFileName & ".xlsm"

Sheets("Import").Copy


With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = ""
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "C:" '<~~ The start folder path for the file picker.
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"

End With

NextCode:

With ActiveWorkbook
.SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
.Close False

End With

End Sub
```

Hope this explains a bit :)

Comment: In the code module behind the sheet, you can use `Me` to refer to the sheet itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could re-link the shape macro on the copied sheet:

```vba
Dim sh As Shape, wbNew As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import").Copy
Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wbNew.Sheets("Import")

For Each sh In ws.Shapes
    'relink only if has action set
    If Len(sh.OnAction) > 0 Then
        sh.OnAction = ws.CodeName & ".Zoom_Click"
    End If
Next sh

'save the new workbook...
```

See also: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/correcting-shape-assigned-macro-links-after-copying-worksheet-vba which has a good general-purpose approach.

Comment: Perfect,  thank you so much Tim,   this really made my evening here.  I have been twisting my head and searching around to find the solution.   Thank you so much again.

Comment: Im using this thread again as the question i had was solved that time.   However i have a new question around the copy of sheet to new workbook.   In the sheet im copying i have a list with images - these images are inserted via link to where the images are.  But is it possible to save the images as an image within the sheet when copying it over to the new workbook ?    As it is today i need to have the images on my pc or access to internet (if i use the url)  in order for them to show in the sheet.

Comment: If you have a new question then it's best to create a new post for it.